# error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag when encrypt RSA public key - passing from the other device

Tags: java, android, rsa, public-key-encryption

I've receivced RSA public key from another device.
and I create public key with these byte arrays for encrypt any strings.
but my public key is invalid.

retrevie many questions but i don't know why it happens.
please help me.

step is below.

1. passing from public key - byte arrays - another device.
2. generate PublicKey object with X509EncodedKeySpec.

> ```
>  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
>  for ( byte key : mKey ) builder.append(key);
>  byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(builder.toString().getBytes("utf-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
>
>  PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new
>  X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes));
> ```

mKey are byte arrays of public key.

but now, exception occured.

exception :

```
03-23 15:23:53.468    5641-5641/updator.firmware.mpaio.samilcts.com.mpaiofirmwareupdator W/System.err﹕ java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
03-23 15:23:53.468    5641-5641/updator.firmware.mpaio.samilcts.com.mpaiofirmwareupdator W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPublicKey(OpenSSLKey.java:101)
03-23 15:23:53.468    5641-5641/updator.firmware.mpaio.samilcts.com.mpaiofirmwareupdator W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.java:47)
03-23 15:23:53.468    5641-5641/updator.firmware.mpaio.samilcts.com.mpaiofirmwareupdator W/System.err﹕ at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:171)
03-23 15:23:53.468    5641-5641/updator.firmware.mpaio.samilcts.com.mpaiofirmwareupdator W/System.err﹕ at updator.firmware.mpaio.samilcts.com.mpaiofirmwareupdator.MainActivity.processGenerateKeyForUpdate(MainActivity.java:253)
03-23 15:23:53.468    5641-5641/updator.firmware.mpaio.samilcts.com.mpaiofirmwareupdator W/System.err﹕ at updator.firmware.mpaio.samilcts.com.mpaiofirmwareupdator.MainActivity.access$1600(MainActivity.java:53)
03-23 15:23:53.468    5641-5641/updator.firmware.mpaio.samilcts.com.mpaiofirmwareupdator W/System.err﹕ at updator.firmware.mpaio.samilcts.com.mpaiofirmwareupdator.MainActivity$5.handleMessage(MainActivity.java:411)
03-23 15:23:53.468    5641-5641/updator.firmware.mpaio.samilcts.com.mpaiofirmwareupdator W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

cf.
received PublicKey byte arrays :

> '0x47, 0x95, 0x1a, 0xe6, 0xf1, 0xba, 0x31, 0x3b, 0x73, 0xc7, 0x79,
>   0x75, 0x72, 0xc6, 0x6d, 0xcc, 0xf0, 0x6b, 0x0f, 0xfa, 0x16, 0x0e,
>   0xed, 0x2d, 0x85, 0xeb, 0x17, 0x89, 0x91, 0x83, 0x59, 0x64, 0xda,
>   0x04, 0x69, 0x31, 0x45, 0x16, 0x73, 0x1b, 0x46, 0xab, 0xe0, 0x2d,
>   0x6e, 0xda, 0x7d, 0x51, 0xc9, 0x2b, 0xc6, 0xe9, 0x73, 0x19, 0x2e,
>   0x3d, 0x39, 0x12, 0xd6, 0x44, 0xf8, 0x71, 0xe0, 0x49, 0xc4, 0x54,
>   0xd5, 0xd1, 0xe9, 0x1f, 0x03, 0x6f, 0xd6, 0x2b, 0xf9, 0x77, 0xd8,
>   0x83, 0x7e, 0x9d, 0x1d, 0xf7, 0x46, 0x5d, 0xf4, 0xac, 0x9f, 0x6b,
>   0xe7, 0x2a, 0x68, 0xb9, 0x55, 0x01, 0xd3, 0xde, 0xbb, 0x1b, 0x93,
>   0x3b, 0x0a, 0x78, 0xe2, 0x06, 0x1c, 0x5d, 0x18, 0x61, 0x2d, 0x8f,
>   0x23, 0x4e, 0x3c, 0xbb, 0x35, 0xa5, 0x99, 0xb4, 0x2f, 0x9b, 0x9d,
>   0x2b, 0x67, 0xfb, 0x89, 0xba, 0x1c, 0x8f, 0x48, 0x9c, 0xa7, 0x99,
>   0x5d, 0xa0, 0x11, 0xe6, 0x1d, 0x5a, 0xd2, 0x18, 0x03, 0xc5, 0x98,
>   0xf5, 0x26, 0xb2, 0x14, 0xaa, 0xfd, 0x77, 0x8e, 0x78, 0x36, 0xc4,
>   0x46, 0xb2, 0xea, 0xd0, 0xa2, 0x5d, 0xb9, 0xc5, 0xae, 0x47, 0x17,
>   0xc1, 0x93, 0x42, 0x12, 0x9c, 0x3a, 0xa0, 0x71, 0xb5, 0x32, 0x51,
>   0x74, 0xa0, 0x6d, 0x2b, 0xbe, 0xc8, 0x4f, 0xc4, 0xf3, 0x5f, 0xd3,
>   0x4f, 0x6b, 0xf9, 0x7a, 0x5d, 0xfa, 0x93, 0x8f, 0xf2, 0x00, 0x1a,
>   0x92, 0x18, 0x41, 0xd5, 0x83, 0x06, 0x98, 0xeb, 0x38, 0x86, 0xbe,
>   0x3c, 0x20, 0xe5, 0x19, 0xdf, 0x8c, 0xac, 0x38, 0x83, 0x5e, 0xde,
>   0x33, 0x62, 0x33, 0x14, 0xee, 0xe3, 0x6c, 0x6b, 0x02, 0xee, 0x0a,
>   0xfe, 0x79, 0x5e, 0x32, 0x8c, 0x2e, 0x20, 0x05, 0x59, 0xed, 0x98,
>   0x89, 0xf1, 0x9b, 0xbf, 0x5a, 0x21, 0x25, 0x1d, 0x51, 0x65, 0x0e,
>   0xbd, 0x03, 0xde, '

thank you.

Comment: This doesn't look like an RSA public key to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. uhm. Do you mean that RSA public key is wrong?

Comment: I mean it just looks like a bunch of random bytes with no structure. It's not supposed to be a mystery. Find out what format the key is supposed to be in.

Comment: Passing public key is right format. It has been proven in the other RSA decryption platform.(but i don't know in android and java api). ^^;;

Comment: Here's the deal: an RSA public key consists of an RSA modulus and a public exponent. There are various standard formats that can be used. Java's X509EncodedSpec expects the format to be a SubjectPublicKey info DER-encoded ASN.1 object, as per [RFC 5280](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1). That hex dump is *not* a SubjectPublicKeyInfo. So saying it is in the 'right' format is automatically wrong. The question is: what format *is* it in?

Comment: oh, that's right. thank you very much!! according to your opinion, i could find solution. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204659/how-to-get-public-rsa-key-from-unformatted-string.) thank you very much.